# Over heating Dodge Avenger

Tags: coolant

So, my radiator hose exploded off , got the new one on and now it’s overheating on idle I put water in it until it’s fixed because I don’t want to spend a lot of money on coolant when it couldn’t be all the way fixed, is the water causing the over heat or is there a additional problem? (2013 Dodge Avenger )

Comment: It will overheat on plain water.

Answer (score 1):

Water doesn't help the situation that's for sure but it sounds like your coolant is not circulating in the system properly or maybe you cooling fans are not coming on. One common thing to cause the coolant not to flow would be the thermostat getting stuck closed. It would be the first thing I checked along with if the fans are coming on or not.